# Error : unmatched character (') while implementing macros in verilog

Tags: verilog

Trying to implement macro's in a simple code.

```
define MEM_SIZE 1024

module hello_world;

  initial
    begin
      $display('MEM_SIZE);
    end
endmodule
```

When executing this then getting below given error:-

```
unmatched character (')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you used single quotes (`'`) instead of back-tick (`` ` ``) `` $display( `MEM_SIZE) ``

Code :

```
`define MEM_SIZE 1024

module hello_world;

initial begin
  $display(`MEM_SIZE);
end
endmodule
```